# How to select Wordpress post category instead of type in functions.php query

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I need to adjust the following code snippet, so it does not exclude Wordpress posts by post type, but by post category?

More specifically, I want to exclude posts from the Wordpress post category with the id 4 in my functions.php file.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param bool    $should_index
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function exclude_post_types( $should_index, WP_Post $post )
{
    // Add all post types you don't want to make searchable.
    $excluded_post_types = array( 'page' );
    if ( false === $should_index ) {
        return false;
    }

    return ! in_array( $post->post_type, $excluded_post_types, true );
}
add_filter( 'test_should_index_searchable_post', 'exclude_post_types', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pre_get_posts`. Codex link for [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function exclude_category_type_from_search( $query ) {

  if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-22, -21' );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_type_from_search', 10 );
```